# Filter any system log file by date or date range

Tags: command-line, log, systemd-journald

#### What I want to achieve:

I'd like to filter a system log file by date, i.e. when I do:

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "error\|warn\|kernel"
```

it prints lines like these for the three last days let say:

```
(...)
Apr  3 06:17:38 computer_name kernel: [517239.805470] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
(...)
Apr  4 19:34:21 computer_name kernel: [517242.523165] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
(...)
Apr  5 09:00:52 computer_name kernel: [517242.523217] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
```

How to grep (select, or filter):

- by date?
- by date+hour?

#### What I tried:

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "Apr  5" | grep -i "error\|warn\|kernel"
```

It works as expected on the `syslog` file, but not on the `kern.log` file for example, which only returns: `Binary file (standard input) matches`.      And when I `tail` this particular file I can see the same starting date format than in the `syslog` file.

#### Question:

How to achieve the same on other logs like the `kern.log` file?

In addition, is it possible to filter:

- by date range?
- by date+hour range?

*Hint:* if possible, with "easy-to-remember commands".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`systemd` gives us `journalctl` which allows filtering like this:

```
journalctl --since "2 days ago"  
journalctl --since "today"
journalctl --since "yesterday --until "today" 
journalctl --since "2019-03-10" --until "2019-03-11 03:00"
journalctl -b # since last boot 
journalctl -k # kernel messages
journalctl -p err # by priority like (emerg|alert|crit|err|warning|info|debug)
journalctl -u sshd # for a particular unit 
journalctl _UID=1000 # for a particular user id
```

Examples can be combined!

Comment: Ok now this is so cool!

Comment: Often not even `sudo` is required (in particular if the user is member of the `adm` group, which the "main" user usually is).

Answer (score 6):

In general, the `kern.log` is a text file. But sometimes it happens that it contains some *binary* data, especially when the system has crashed before and the system could not close the file properly. You may then notice lines containing text like `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@` and such.

If `grep` notices its input is *binary*, it usually stops further processing and prints `... binary file ...` instead. But there's a switch to change this behaviour. From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/grep.1.html):

> ```
> [...]
> File and Directory Selection
>    -a, --text
>           Process a binary file as if it were text; 
>           this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.
> [...]
> ```

You can try the following:

```
$ grep -a -i "Apr  5" /var/log/kern.log  | grep -i "error\|warn\|kernel"
```

(But I would actually prefer the `journalctl` solution given in another answer.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy log file viewer called [`lnav`](https://lnav.org/), that supports many filtering options, including *in/out* filters, as well as time filtering.

Install with: (have Universe repository enabled)

```
sudo apt install lnav
```

To filter on dates, use the internal commands:

```
:hide-lines-after <date>
:hide-lines-before <date>
```

Date ranges are reset with the command:

```
:show-lines-before-and-after
```

These are invoked by pressing <kbd>:</kbd> and then typing the command, and can be combined with any *in/out* filters on keywords.

I wish there were an even easier way to filter on dates, but currently this seems to be the best way.